# How to delete skype chat history stored on hotmail/live/outlook.com?

Tags: skype, history, hotmail, microsoft-account, outlook.com

Please note, I'm not talking about the skype chat history on the skype software, which I can easly delete by going to Tools/Options/Privacy, etc...

I'm talking about that all of my chat conversations I do on skype using the normal skype software are also being saved on the cloud!

I'm using a microsoft account to login to skype since this is an old account I have with lots of contacts that I used to have since the Messenger, so I keep using that.

Yes, even I have no history on skype, if I logging into my account I can see all my previous chat history since the begining of the time, I've gone back a couple of months browsing and it seems everything is there, all my conversations with all my contacts are on the web, despite I explicitly told skype to not keep history (and it obeys, but just for the desktop).

I have searched and wasted hours on google trying to find and only could find a single thread with the same complain I have now. Most of the articles I found are garbage related to the normal procedure for deleting the history.

I also found articles where they say I supposedly have a "Message History" folder in my outlook account, which I don't have now, and I don't recall ever had that. Supposedly I could delete it from there, but I don't have it.

Oh, please note this too. While I have my privacy settings to not keep history at all, my current day chat history can be viewed on outlook/hotmail website. It is if I go to another sections, say, "Profile", while having the Chat opened that I realized all my conversations are there, stored for months. I don't want that and can't find a way to do it.

So, either this is a big glitch or something so obvious that I'm missing.

**This is how to see your message history.**
Go to live.com/hotmail, and log with your microsoft account. Activate the chat pane by clicking the happy face smiley icon. Now click on your name and go to your profile. Keep the chat pane open. Click any contact and browse your chat history back. It seems it stores the full past month as I just did this and the history stops exactly on Sep, 3.

How to delete skype chat history stored on outlook.com?

Comment: Yes, I used to have a Messenger account, so I use that same to login to skype, too.

Comment: I assume your logging into `Skype` using your `Microsoft Account` instead of your `Skype` account? Have you tried to clear out the local cache of the messages you did have saved? While the option you talk about would stop future logging, its not clear, if the messages you see online are new or old.  It might help if you describe how to view these chat messages because I can't figure it out.

Comment: It's been a while. This problem also annoys me a lot! Did you find some method to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It's related to connected contacts

if your contacts keep the history when you open the chat window the old chat sync with his history

so you have to delete the history on both side, yours and your contact side too

if you have sensitive talk just ask your contact to delete the chat history and do it your side too

you have to know that everything is kept on the Microsoft backup server even if you figure out how to delete them in both client side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Skype options to not save conversation history?
By default this is checked in Skype. You may uncheck it so the messages are not saved in Outlook.

[image]